# Stubbing when an object's constructor builds another object

Tags: ruby, constructor, rspec, stubbing, rr

So I've got some code that, grossly simplified, looks like this:

```
class B
  def initialize opts
    @opts = opts
  end
end

class A
  def initialize opts
    # defaults etc applied to opts
    @b = B.new opts
  end
end
```

In other words, when I initialize A with options, it creates a B and passes a modified set of options to it.

I would like to test that B.new gets the correct arguments.  Right now, I'm doing it like this, using RSpec/RR:

```
@b = Object.new
# stub methods on @b here
stub(B).new { |options|
  options[:foo].should == 'whatever'
  @b
}
A.new({:foo => 'whatever'})
```

But this has two problems.

First, I can't instantiate an actual copy of `B` with the actual options.  If I call B.new inside the block, it calls the stubbed version and loops until the stack pops.  I *can* set `@b = B.new` before the stubbing, but I don't know the options that will be passed in yet, defeating the point of the test.

(And before somebody calls me out on it: yes, in strict unit test dogma, a test of A *should* stub out any methods in B, and needing to stub out a lot means your code is bad in the first place.)

Second, it just feels wrong to put the `should` in the setup of the test, instead of in a separate `it ... do ... end` block afterwards.  But since I can't create an actual `B` (see above), I can't really interrogate its post-construction state either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write something like `B.should_receive(:new).with({:foo => 'whatever'})`.

Personally, I avoid stubbing/mocking and would rather test for behavior; the fact that a new `B` is created with a given set of options is implementation dependent and I wouldn't test that directly.

Comment: D'oh!  Thanks, can't believe I didn't see that way of doing it earlier.  Adding RR version as separate answer.

Answer (score 10):

The `should` syntax from [Marc-André Lafortune's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11356236/27358) appears to be deprecated in RSpec 3. The following `expect` syntax seems to work, however:

```
expect(B).to receive(:new).with(foo: 'whatever')
```

Note that if you want `B.new` to return a specific instance (e.g. a test double), you can use `and_return`:

```
b = instance_double(B)
expect(B).to receive(:new).with(foo: 'whatever').and_return(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

RR version of Marc-Andre's answer:

```
before do
  stub(B).new { @b }
end

it 'uses the correct options' do
  B.should have_received.new(hash_including(:foo => 'whatever'))
end
```